# libmodbus передача пакета по RTU rs-485

Tags: c++, c, library, modbus, libmodbus

Кто работал с библиотекой [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org/) подскажите пожалуйста.
Хочу в устройство принимающая данный по протоколу MODBUS отправить сам пакет.

Приведу кусок кода со структурой самого пакета:

```
struct input_t
{
union
{
    uint16_t raw[9];
    struct {
        uint16_t mode;
        float position;
        float time;
        float ampl;
        float velocity;
    } __attribute__((packed));
};
static constexpr int addr = 1;
static constexpr int count = sizeof(raw) / 2;
};
```

В основной части приложения мне достаточно просто отправить этот пакет по COM PORT по RTU:

```
modbus_t* ctx;
input_t ifield;
output_t ofield;

std::cout << "Sizeof input : " << sizeof(input_t) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Sizeof output: " << sizeof(output_t) << std::endl;

//ctx = modbus_new_tcp("192.168.0.3", 502);
ctx = modbus_new_rtu("COM4", 115200, 'N', 8, 1);
if( ctx == NULL ) {
    std::cout << "Unable to create the libmodbus context";
    return -1;
}

modbus_set_slave(ctx, 1);
modbus_set_debug(ctx, FALSE);
std::cout << "Connect: " << modbus_connect(ctx) << std::endl;
uint16_t tab_reg[64];
if (ctx ==NULL)
    printf("%s\n","check null not ok" );
int a = modbus_read_registers(ctx, input_t::addr, input_t::count, ofield.raw);
std::cout << a << std::endl;
std::cout << *ofield.raw << std::endl;

ifield.mode = 3;
ifield.position = -9;
ifield.time = 6;

int b = modbus_write_registers(ctx, output_t::addr, output_t::count, ofield.raw);
std::cout << a << std::endl;

modbus_close(ctx);
modbus_free(ctx);
return 0;
```

В данной программе подключение к данному порту и и к ведомому происходит корректно. Ошибки возникают на функциях отправки пакета и считывания регистров.С чем это может быть связанно?

Comment: какие ошибки хоть?

Comment: код ошибки -1, Unknown error.

Comment: вы чем нибудь проверяли подключение устройства кроме своего кода?

Comment: Да подключение проверял, есть тула которая с Gui интерфейсом и она так же подключается по тому же компорту. Подключаюсь не паралельно, во время подключения с помощью утилиты кодом подключится уже не могу так как порт занят.

Comment: насчет ком-порта, COM4 замените на \\\\.\\COM4, если дело под виндой

Comment: Заменил но ошибки так и остались. Так же на сколько я понимаю в последней версии библиотеки уже можно подключаться как COM4 так как ошибок по поводу подключения не выдает

Comment: в общем, для всех функций проверяйте код возврата и errno, -1 вам возвращает modbus_read_registers и код ошибки в  errno, станет понятнее хоть

Comment: modbus_read_registers обычно падает, если запрашиваете слишком много, можно попробовать позапрашивать фиксом modbus_read_registers(ctx, 0, 1, tab_reg); чтобы убедиться, что девайс дает респонс

Comment: К комментарию @goldstar_labs, можно добавить еще следующее: используйте функцию `modbus_strerror`. Например: `if (modbus_...(ctx) == -1) fprintf(stderr, modbus_strerror(errno));`

Comment: Кроме того, в приведённом, вами фрагменте кода есть нестыковки. А именно, при чтение регистров, вы читаете в `tab_reg`. выводите `ofield.raw`. Так же, при записи, присваиваете значения полям переменной `ifield`, а по факту пытаетесь записать значения `ofield`.

Comment: По поводу нестыковок , я тестил и вставил неправильный код , уже поправил. Но суть в ошибках так и осталась.

Comment: добавте функцию `modbus_set_error_recovery(ctx,(MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_LINK | MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_PROTOCOL));` перед подключением.

Comment: Функция modbus_set_error_recovery судя из мануала пытается просто приконектиться, моя ошибка заключается в считывании и записи информации на устройство/с устройства. Прошу внимательней прочитать проблему описанную выше. Подключение функции не помогло. Может быть хоть кто то работал по RTU очень нужно решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение данной проблемы может быть не очевидно и решена она была методом тыка во все функции. Надеюсь что кому то когда то это поможет. Решение следующее , нужно было всего лишь установить время timeout. Хотя в документации к использованию данной библиотеки - [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org/), сказано что данные переменные устанавливаются по дефолту. Ниже приведу код работающей программы про протоколу RTU, для операционной системы windows, для nix-подобных систем нужно будет только поменять порт с COMX на /dev/ttyUSBX.

Структура пакета:

```
struct massage
{
union
{
    uint16_t raw[9];
    struct {
        uint16_t mode;
        float position;
        float time;
        float ampl;
        float velocity;
    } __attribute__((packed));
};
 static constexpr int addr = 256 ;
 static constexpr int count = sizeof(raw) / 2;
};
```

Основная функция для приема и передачи данный по RTU:

```
ctx = modbus_new_rtu("COM4", 19200, 'N', 8, 1);
if (NULL == ctx)
{
                printf("Unable to create libmodbus context\n");
                res = 1;
}
else
{
    printf("created libmodbus context\n");
    modbus_set_debug(ctx, TRUE);
    modbus_set_error_recovery(ctx,MODBUS_ERROR_RECOVERY_PROTOCOL);
    rc = modbus_set_slave(ctx, 1);
    modbus_get_response_timeout(ctx, &tv_sec, &tv_usec); 
    tv_sec = 60;
    tv_usec = 0;

    modbus_set_response_timeout(ctx, tv_sec,tv_usec); 
    modbus_get_response_timeout(ctx, &tv_sec, &tv_usec); 


    rc = modbus_connect(ctx);
    printf("modbus_connect: %d \n",rc);

    if (rc == -1) {
        printf("Connection failed: %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
        res = 1;
    }

    rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, massage::addr, massage::count, out.raw);
    rc = modbus_write_registers(ctx, massage::addr, massage::count, out.raw);


    modbus_close(ctx);
    modbus_free(ctx);
}
```